# Comparing values in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following array in my view.py

```
chapter = 5
number_of_chapters = 5
selected_chapters = list()
for index in range(1, number_of_chapters+1):
    selected_chapters.append(index)
return render(request, 'verses.html', {'chapter': chapter, 'selected_chapters': selected_chapters})
```

but when I try to compare entries in this list with `chapter` it never returns true

**template**

```
<select name="c" id="chapter" value="{{ chapter }}" onchange="bible_search(true);">
    <option value="1">Chapter</option>
    {% for c in selected_chapters %}
        <option {% if c == chapter %}  selected {% endif %} value="{{ c }}">{{ c }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I am wondering if I need to convert a string to an int somewhere or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you haven't posted the full code since this works fine for me. Using code you presented, when I navigate to the page rendered from that view, I see have a `select` with the value `5` selected. I assume that's what you want? This suggests to me that there's some conflict elsewhere in the view or the template.

While we're here, HTML `select` elements do not have a `value` attribute so that should be removed. Secondly, you have two `option` elements with the same value. Here's the HTML as rendered in the browser.

```
<select name="c" id="chapter" value="5" onchange="bible_search(true);">
    <option value="1">Chapter</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option selected="" value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The only difference between my code and the sample I gave is the fact that the number of chapters is retrieved from the database. This where I needed to convert it to an int. It works now.